# how to remove the quotes or get element from this (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

As topic, how can I remove the quote in the picuture below or get the img element from this?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdPAP.png)

I m new to javascript and start making an image slider that can pop up a window while clicked to the image.

I cloned the li object which is clicked, and try to open it in the new window, it do work but how can I get the img only without the li?

Right now i m trying to call the cloned this object with innerHTML, but it shows the img element with quote, is there any way to remove the quote?
[the quote that i want to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdPAP.png)

first time ask a question in here, if i violate any rules in the post, i delete the post, sorry for causing any inconvenience.

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .risuto1 {
            max-width: 480px;
            max-height: 270px;

            margin: auto;
            position: relative;
        }

        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .aitemu>img {
            max-width: 100%;
        }

        .aitemu {
            display: none;
            position: relative;
        }

        .aitemu.akutibu {
            display: block;
        }

        .risuto1>.mae,
        .tsugi {
            width: auto;
            height: auto;

            padding: 20px;
            top: 102.6px;

            position: absolute;

            cursor: pointer;

            background-color: red;
        }

        .risuto1>.tsugi {
            left: 431.8px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        var risuto1 = document.createElement("div");
        risuto1.classList.add("risuto1");
        document.body.appendChild(risuto1);

        var suraidaaitemu = document.createElement("ul");
        suraidaaitemu.classList.add("suraidaaitemu");
        risuto1.appendChild(suraidaaitemu);

        var imejisosurisuto = ["https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CGGc3wKVEAAjmWj?format=jpg&name=medium", "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EYCXvuzU8AEepqD?format=jpg&name=large", "https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/cdn.bibi-star.jp/production/imgs/images/000/668/074/original.jpg?1626914998", "https://livedoor.blogimg.jp/rin20064/imgs/7/3/73251146.jpg", "https://www.tbs.co.jp/anime/oregairu/character/img/chara_img_02.jpg"]
        //var imejirisuto=[]

        for (var n = 0; n < imejisosurisuto.length; n++) {
            var imeji = document.createElement("img");
            imeji.src = imejisosurisuto[n];

            var aitemu = document.createElement("li");
            aitemu.classList.add("aitemu");
            suraidaaitemu.appendChild(aitemu);

            aitemu.appendChild(imeji);

            aitemu.onclick=atarashivindou;
        }

        var akutibunasaishonoko = document.querySelector(".suraidaaitemu").firstChild;
        akutibunasaishonoko.classList.add("akutibu");

        var mae = document.createElement("div");
        mae.classList.add("mae");
        mae.innerHTML = "&#10094";
        risuto1.appendChild(mae);

        var tsugi = document.createElement("div");
        tsugi.classList.add("tsugi");
        tsugi.innerHTML = "&#10095";
        risuto1.appendChild(tsugi);

        var tensuu = 0;
        var suraido = document.querySelector(".suraidaaitemu").children;
        var gokeisuraido = suraido.length;

        tsugi.onclick = function () {
            Tsugi("Tsugi");
        }

        mae.onclick = function () {
            Tsugi("Mae");
        }

        function Tsugi(houkou) {
            if (houkou == "Tsugi") {
                tensuu++;
                if (tensuu == gokeisuraido) {
                    tensuu = 0;
                }
            }
            else {
                if (tensuu == 0) {
                    tensuu = gokeisuraido - 1;
                }
                else {
                    tensuu--;
                }
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < suraido.length; i++) {
                suraido[i].classList.remove("akutibu");
            }
            suraido[tensuu].classList.add("akutibu");
        }

        function atarashivindou(){
            var Atarashivindou = window.open("", "_blank", "width: 1000px, max-height: 562.5px");

            var kakudaigazou=document.createElement("div");
            kakudaigazou.classList.add("kakudaigazou");
            Atarashivindou.document.body.appendChild(kakudaigazou);

            var koronaitemu=this.cloneNode(true);
            var koronimeji=koronaitemu.innerHTML;
            kakudaigazou.append(koronimeji);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.innerHTML` is a string. You don't want to append a string, but the element. So change this:

```
        var koronaitemu=this.cloneNode(true);
        var koronimeji=koronaitemu.innerHTML;
        kakudaigazou.append(koronimeji);
```

...to this:

```
        var koronimeji=this.querySelector("img").cloneNode();
        kakudaigazou.append(koronimeji);
```